# Why $SO(3)$ action is exact?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

In McDuff&Salamon's book(P207 Example 5.3.1), they claim that

> Consider the diagonal action of $SO(3)$ on the phase space $\mathbb{R}^6 $ (with the standard symplectic structure) by $\psi_\Phi(x,y):=(\Phi X, \Phi Y)$ for $\Phi \in SO(3)$.  A simple calculation shows that this action is exact, which means for $\lambda=\sum y_idx_i$, $\psi_\Phi^*\lambda=\lambda$.

I try to calculate it, but fault. Here is my calculation:

> Assume $\psi_\Phi^*\sum y_idx_i=\sum c_idx_i+e_idy_i$, then
>
> $c_1=\psi_\Phi^*\sum (y_idx_i)(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})$
>
> $=\sum (y_i dx_i)(\psi_{\Phi*} \frac{\partial}{\partial x})$
>
> $=\Phi_{11}y_1+\Phi_{21}y_2+\Phi_{31}y_3$,
>
> which should be equal to $y_1$

I wonder what is my fault, is my calculation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source of your mistake: $g^*y^i \neq y^i$, you have to compose through $g$.

Here's a very ugly proof with lots of coordinates and indices:

First, take any $g\in SO(3)$. The action of this $g$ in $\mathbb{R}^6$ is the diagonal one as you stated. Let us calculate it's "infinitesimal action", namely its pushforward on vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$. Since $g$ is already linear, this is easy:

$$
g\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right) = g^{k}_{~i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} 
$$
$$
g\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}\right) = g^{k}_{~i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^k} 
$$
This is nothing but the matrix expression of $g$ in the canonical basis in $\mathbb{R}^6$! Now let's calculate the action on the functions $y^i$. Pullback of functions is given by composition from behind. Take any arbitrary point $(x',y')\in\mathbb{R}^6$:

$$
(g^*y^i)(x',y') = (y^i\circ g)(x',y') = y^i(g\cdot x',g\cdot y') = (g\cdot y')^i = g^{i}_{~l}y^l
$$
The above is simply a messier way of saying $g_*(v,w) = (gv, gw)$ where matrix multiplication is implied in the RHS, but the coordinate expression will be useful. The pullback acting on $dx^i$ can be evaluated by taking an arbitrary vector $(v,w)\in T_p\mathbb{R}^6\simeq \mathbb{R}^6$ and
$$
(g^*dx^i)(v,w) = dx^i(g_* v, g_* w)=(gv)^i = g^i_{~j}v^j = (g^i_{~j}dx^j)(v,w)
$$
for any vector $(v,w)$, so we deduce $g^*dx^i = g^i_{~j} dx^j$. Now to calculate the pullback of $\lambda$:
$$
g^*\lambda = g^*\left(y^i dx^i\right) =  g^*(y^i) g^*(dx^i) = g^i_{~l} y^l g^i_{~j} dx^j = (g^t)^l_{~i} g^i_{~j} y^l dx^j = \delta^j_l y^l dx^j = y^j dx^j = \lambda
$$

**Remarks**: I have used the summation convantion to avoid writting many $\sum$'s. There are ways to write all of this coordinate free, but I thought maybe this was helpful at this point.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I forget to pullback y in ydx